# What are the differences between "shop," "shoppe," and "store"?

Tags: meaning

What are the differences between *shop*, *shoppe*, and *store*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While I like @Jigar Joshi's answer, I'll provide some American Connotation, if I can. *(Caveat, not a professional culturist)*

## Shop

I would say that a `shop` is somewhere you go to have a service preformed, or only provides a single or narrowly focused good.  Usually contains a `workshop` of some kind where the goods are made on-site for the customer.

- `Body Shop` refers to an auto repair facility (autobody shop)
- `Wood Shop` refers to a place where you can go to get custom woodworking done
- `Coffee Shop` a place you can go to get hand-made drinks
- `Butcher's Shop` a place to get custom cuts of meat

## Store

I would say that a `store` is the more common American term for a place you go to buy something.  They usually have many different sections and offer a wider variety of goods than a `shop`.  The goods you purchase are usually made off-site and only stored on location.

- `Department Store` buy furnishings and clothes for each room of the house
- `Grocery Store` buy food and many other consumables
- `Online Store` buy anything! :D

## Shoppe

Generally a fancier term, as @Jigar Joshi mentioned, to give an air of authenticity and aristocracy.

- `Coffee Shoppe` here you can buy *even more* expensive fancy coffee.

But where ever you go, you'll end up `shopping` regardless of the `store`.

Comment: Its **Joshi** :)

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, oops I'll fix it.

Comment: One more point :) System won't notify me if you will write `@Jigar Joshi` you need to start with `@org`  :) Nice answer

Comment: @org, you could just swap your name around then.  You can put a link in your profile.

Comment: *Store* is only used in British English for department stores, like Macy's or Selfridges. Any other time, we would say *shop*. Some retailers may brand themselves as *superstores*, but they're still just shops.

Answer (score 10):

I'm presuming you're referring to these words used as nouns to mean a mercantile business of some sort. Historically, *stores* were businesses which kept inventory to be sold and *shops* where businesses where items were manufactured or repaired. Nowadays, *shop* and *store* are generally synonymous, but each has slightly more typical uses depending on what is being sold.

In my part of the world (Canada) you would generally refer to most commercial places of business as a *store* (grocery, convenience, clothes, book, furniture) while *shops* are reserved for repair, flowers, or gifts (*gift shop* is quite idiomatic.) Thus, you would typically hear bicycle shop, rather than store, because repairs are done there. It would not sound that strange to hear *shop* when referring to clothes, book or furniture stores, however.

*Shoppe* is an archaic spelling of *shop* and is used only in proper names of places wanting to sound quaint and old-fashioned. [*The Pop Shoppe*](http://www.thepopshoppe.com/) and [*The Medicine Shoppe*](http://www.medicineshoppe.ca/) are a couple canadian examples.

Comment: We make fun of stores with "Shoppe" in their name by pronouncing it as two syllables, with separate and highly-stressed p's.

Comment: @Martha Alas, that's also how some people believe my last name should be pronounced… ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In England and Australia a shop is what North Americans refer to as a store.  A shop is a place for conducting retail business.

As pointed out above, some retailers may brand their shop as a Megastore because the term store has become trendy in advertising but it is nevertheless still a shop.

Store only applies to a 'department store' (a shop with several departments) or a 'general store' in a village or small community which sells a variety of essentials.

Another international curiosity:  I notice in the spread of English in German websites, they have online shops rather than stores.

Answer (score 0):

In American English:

**Store** - A place to purchase things.

**Shop** - I think primarily is used as a short form of *'workshop'*.  I don't hear it being used very often as a synonym of 'store', although it is a valid usage.

**Shoppe** - Used on stores to make them sound medieval.

Comment: There are a few idiomatic cases where *shop* is more common when you might expect *store*, at least in my part of the world. *Gift shop* and *flower shop* come to mind.

Answer (score -1):

A store usually 'stores' perishable items. Shoppe is a mediaeval term which is unlikely to have been in actual use when the shop was first opened, unless it is *very* old. Shops can sell anything, and I would say include a store.