# Is the preposition optional in "going down (to) the store"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, british-english, dialects

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/down-downwards-or-downward?q=Down%252C%2Bdownwards%2Bor%2Bdownward) says:
In informal situations, we can use **down** to talk about a quick trip to a destination which we consider to be less central than where we are. In this meaning, we can use it with or without to. Without *to* is less formal:

> I’m just going down (to) the shop. Do you want anything?
>
> Are you going down (to) the golf club tonight?

Is Cambridge wrong here?

I haven't ever heard "I am going down the shop" unless used to say "I'm perusing the aisles of a store", and not "I am going to the shop."

Maybe it's different in the UK? I can't even see how this would begin to be right.

I understand that

> - I am going down the store

and

> - I am going down to the store

are two different things. Is there a dialect / is it "informal" to mix those two phrases into the 2nd definition?

Comment: Many people say *down the shore* in the Mid-Atlantic U.S. (New York, New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, Maryland). In Baltimorese, heading to Ocean City is stereotypically rendered *goin downey ayshin*. See e.g. *[“Down the shore” versus “at the beach”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63842) and *[Origin of New Jersey idiom “down the shore”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184716)*

Answer (score 2):

The [Longman Dictionary Online](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go-down) confirms the informal use when omitting "to" in such expressions

> go down the shops/club/park etc British English spoken informal to go to the shops, a club etc
>
> Does anyone want to go down the pub tonight?

At risk of sounding classist, elitist or snobbish, I'd say that the expression is mainly used by the working class and younger people.

A British band called Sham 69 has a song named "[Hurry Up Harry](https://youtu.be/KEEMZ3mGU9g)".

The lyrics include

> We're going down the pub
>
> Come on come on
>
> Hurry up Harry come on
>
> Come on come on
>
> Hurry up Harry come on
>
> We're going down the pub
>
> We're going

[It's better down the pub](https://www.morningadvertiser.co.uk/Article/2013/05/15/It-s-Better-Down-the-Pub-campaign-launched?utm_source=copyright&utm_medium=OnSite&utm_campaign=copyright), a national campaign celebrating Britain's passion for pubs was launched in May 2013.

[image: It's better down the pub dot com]

As far as I know, the word "shop" is also mainly used by British English speakers as opposed to saying "store".

This [EL&U answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/what-are-the-differences-between-shop-shoppe-and-store/9801#9801) as well as [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408129/shop-vs-store-the-verb-usage) cover the meanings and etymology of "shop" and its variations.

Comment: "Down the shop" sounds odd to me, but "down the shops" sounds normal informal; also "down the pub", "down the market". I wouldn't say any of these myself. (BrE speaker).

Comment: also expressions like "Down the dogs" and "Down the chippy", would you say they're regional East London dialect?

Comment: Bookmanu, they are not confined to East London, they can be heard all over the area of England where "Estuary English" is spoken. Interestingly, in Bristol where I live, working class people say "up the dogs" and "up the chippy".